# Class loop creates mysql too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class, mysqli

So I am working with a LOT of classes... Everything was working fine until I included my session class (verifies and creates/destroys sessions) into my user class (does user operations, login, register, etc).

Basically, I am getting a "mysqli Too many connections!" error... I think this is because my sessions class is included in the users class and vice versa:

__construct of class User:

```
$this->db = new DB($db);
$this->password = new Password();
$this->session = new Session($db);
```

$db is just an array of database info...

__construct of class Session:

```
 $this->error = new Error();
 $this->users = new User($db);
 $this->db = new DB($db);
```

So you see how they both are including each other, I think this is what's causing my connection error.

Comment: you'll have to eliminate the loop. if user creates a session which creates a user, which creates a session, etc... you WILL essentially kill your system. Thankfully you're running out mysql connection slots before you run out of memory, but either way, you've got an infinite loop that you'll have to break.

Comment: Creating a new database handle for each user is a bad idea. Don't do this. Instead, use a common connection pool using [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one first, and pass it into the constructor of the other.

Like:

Session:

```
__construct($db){
  $this->db = $db; //Don't reconstruct
  $this->users = new User($db,$this);
  ...
}
```

User:

```
__construct($db,$session){
...
  $this->db = $db; //Don't re-construct
  $this->session = $session;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the user's job to create a database connection. (When you think of it, it doesn't make much sense, does it?)

Instead, **ask** for the database connection in the constructor.

```
class User {
    public function __construct(DB $db) {
```

This way, you can reuse the connection object all over the application.

Answer (score 0):

in the session class

do

```
$this->db = $db;
```

and in your user class

```
$this->session = new Session($this->db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would if you make a third class that constructs with both the two classes and run the loop on the 3rd class? Then run all your DB instances on UserSession? I dont know?

__construct of class User:

```
 $this->password = new Password();
```

__construct of class Session:

```
$this->error = new Error();
```

__construct of class UserSession:

```
$this->db = new DB($db);
$this->users = new User($db);
$this->users = new Session($db);
```